# How to manage Select All with rows of topics with radio buttons

Tags: multi-selection, radio-buttons

I am looking for opinions on how to handle a 'Select All' option for a list of topics that each have a series of radio buttons as options.

Having a 'Select All' for each radio button option in the list is messy. Is there a better method for achieving this action?

### Category 1

```
         Select all  Select all  Select all
Topic 1: ( ) Email   ( ) Letter  ( ) None
Topic 2: ( ) Email               ( ) None
Topic 3: ( ) Email   ( ) Letter
```

### Category 2

```
         Select all  Select all  Select all
Topic 1:             ( ) Letter  ( ) None
Topic 2: ( ) Email   ( ) Letter  ( ) None
Topic 3: ( ) Email               ( ) None
```

Comment: Wouldn't there be some conflicts like: Select all Letter in Category 1, what would happen with Topic 2?

Answer (score 1):

**Perhaps you need to think about the primary purpose of 'Select All'**

Is the purpose to:

1. Ease of input : selecting 'email' for all available topics at once.
2. Ease of reading : Knowing if all are selected or not for a given radio button.
3. Both

It is hard to have both. I am guessing it is (1) to allow ease of input for 100s of rows.

**About the None option**

Like Oke Tega mentioned, None is redundant. Maybe you have some use of it. I would have all Nones selected by default.

**This seems like a good case to use intermediate state of checkboxes, a solution could look like this**

[image]

It only provides the ease of input for the users, ranks low on readability. You could get really creative with color coding too.

If you want to select all available radio buttons for letter, you click the header checkbox which turns to intermediate state and selects all available letter options.

Answer (score 0):

You options are conflicting especially where you have none. If the user doesn't select anything, it's as good as saying none. So depending on how you are going about it, none is not needed

Instead you could put select all among the radio buttons but give a differ t color or style

**Category 1**

```
Topic 1: ( ) Email   ( ) Letter  ( ) Select All
Topic 2: ( ) Email   
Topic 3: ( ) Email   ( ) Letter  ( ) Select All
```

**Category

Topic 1: ( ) Letter 
Topic 2: ( ) Email   ( ) Letter  ( ) Select All
Topic 3: ( ) Email